# Why Boolean TRUE is not TRUE?

Tags: java, boolean

I discover during debbuging my android app the strange behaviour.

**There is expression:**

```
if (r == true)
```

where var `r` has the value `true` but the whole statement is false. I try to use object `Boolean` and also primitive type `boolean`.

I'm sure that I make some basic mistake.

Here is the screen from debbuger.

[image]

**Edit:**

I'm using `java.lang.Boolean`.

method `isSyncRequired` returns `Boolean.TRUE` and it is compared in if-else block.

```
if(isSyncRequired(s))
if (r)
if (r == true)
```

dont't work.

Comment: I forgot... I also try the statement `if(r)`.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why aren't you just doing: 'if(isSyncRequired(s))' or even 'if(r)' you're now comparing a boolean to see if it's true while you could just use the value itself. And when using Boolean use equals not ==

Comment: I firstly use `if(isSyncRequired(s))` but app has got the strange behaviour. Then I start to find the bug. I change it on `if(r)` later on `if(r == true)` etc.

Comment: Try cleaning your project. You may have source code out-of-synch with the compiled classes.

Comment: @GriffeyDog without the success

Comment: @misco: may I suggest forgetting the debugger and going for a simple `System.out.println("r = " + r);` to verify that return value?

Comment: Without debugger it prints true and the comparison is the correct. But why does it happen?

Comment: I rewrited my code. I kept the same return types and values. I removed one method and it seems to work properly. But I don't understand to this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does if(Boolean.TRUE) {...} and if(true) {...} work differently in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546321/why-does-ifboolean-true-and-iftrue-work-differently-in-java)

Comment: @Raedwald Isn't it the other way around? The linked question is a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 11):

Because you're using a capital-B `Boolean`, which is an object, so `==` uses reference equality semantics.

What you should be doing is just

```
if (r)
```

There's no need to test if it's equal to true.  Or inline it:

```
if (isSyncRequired(s)) {
```

Comment: Your rationale does not appear to agree with [the JLS section on boolean equality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.2). According to the JLS, `r` should be unboxed before the comparison. Perhaps this is something Android-specific?

Comment: I distinguish the difference between Object and primitive. But your suggestion dont't work.

Comment: I would agree, but the OP's issue appears to unambiguously indicate that's not working out in their scenario.

Comment: @misco: Give more details, if that doesn't work.  Are you e.g. sure you're using `java.lang.Boolean`?

Comment: @thkala Android? As I understand it Android development uses Java source code, a compiler to generate class files and then a transcoder to create the Dalvik files. All the auto[ub]boxing "fiction" occurs in the Java compiler, so there shouldn't be anything left for the Android piece to mess up. (As usual, see output from `javap -c`.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: true. I am out of ideas, except for Louis' suggestion about the OP not using `java.lang.Boolean` or some weird debugger bug (pun not intended).

Comment: As @thkala already mentioned, it doesn't matter if you use `Boolean` or `boolean`, the language spec clearly states that a) `==` and `!=` comparisons with those types do _not_ use reference equality and b) even if that was the case, the [spec on boxing conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#5.1.7) (its the same for SE7) states that for `boolean`/`Boolean` the resulting objects are guaranteed to be identical. So please remove the first line or your answer, its plain wrong.

Comment: @SimonLehmann: Not without a better explanation as to the OP's problem.

Comment: What explanation could possibly change the language specification? The statement is wrong and will be wrong no matter what anybody explains or discusses.

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares by reference.  You are comparing a `Boolean` object to a `boolean` value.

Use `if (r)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should unbox the `Boolean` value. Try

```
if (r.booleanValue())
```

or

```
if (r.booleanValue() == true)
```