# Why does if(Boolean.TRUE) {...} and if(true) {...} work differently in Java

Tags: java, boolean

I want to know the difference between `Boolean.TRUE` and `true` values inside an `if` clause. Why does it give me a compilation error (that a value may not have been initialized) when I use `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `true`.

Below is my code :

```
public class Test {

    public void method1() {
        int x;
        if(Boolean.TRUE) {
            x = 200;
        }
        System.out.println("x: " + x);   // Compilation error       
    }

    public void method2() {
        int x;
        if(true) {
            x = 200;
        }
        System.out.println("x: " + x);   // Compiles fine
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. What's the point of checking if true is true?

Comment: @LawrenceAiello: you're missing the point of the question. In one case the compiler can correctly identify the expression is always true, in the other it can't.

Comment: It throws an error, but that is "value x may not have been initialized". And that's because behind Boolean.TRUE there could also hide 'false'.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894311/what-is-the-difference-between-boolean-true-and-true-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short answer**
For `if (true)` the compiler can deduce that `x` has been initialized before it's being read. This does not hold for the `if (Boolean.TRUE)` case.

**Formal answer:**
All local variables must have a *definite assignment* before being read ([14.4.2. Execution of Local Variable Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4.2)):

> [...] If a declarator does not have an initialization expression, **then every reference to the variable must be preceded by execution of an assignment to the variable**, or a compile-time error occurs by the rules of §16.

In this case there's an `if` statement involved in the code preceding the reference to the variable, so the compiler performs some flow analysis. However, as spelled out in [Chapter 16. Definite Assignment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html):

> Except for the special treatment of the conditional boolean operators `&&`, `||`, and `? :` and of **boolean-valued constant expressions**, the values of expressions are not taken into account in the flow analysis.

So since `true` is a boolean-valued [constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) and `Boolean.TRUE` (which is a reference to a value on the heap, subject to auto-unboxing etc) [is not](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) it follows that

```
if (true) {
    x = 200;
}
```

yields a definite assignment of `x` while

```
if (Boolean.TRUE) {
    x = 200;
}
```

does not.

Answer (score 5):

The difference exists because one is a true constant while the other is just mimicking one.

The compiler will look at things like `if` statements and try to figure out whether they will always be a given expression (`== true`, `== false`, `== null`, etc) but it will only do this up to a certain level.

In the case of `true` there is no ambiguity: it will always undoubtedly represent "true". However `Boolean.TRUE` is just a field, which is apparently not as far as the compiler is willing to go.

```
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);
```

Think for example about what would be done if reflection is involved.

You can see this clearly when you introduce an extra level of complexity:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x;
    if(getCondition()) {
        x = 5;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
} 

private static boolean getCondition(){
    return true;
}
```

Even though the expression will always be true, the compiler still complains that `x` might be unassigned. Only the most rudimentary verification is done to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It does throw this error because it does not know what hides behind `Boolean.TRUE`. `TRUE` is a static field of the type boolean in the class Boolean, but its value could also be `false`. It isn't obviously, 'though.